# Nested object structure

Tags: javascript

In the following Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dzddv6pa/

```
console.clear();

var data = {
    "apps": [{
        "appName": "App1",
        "subApps": [{
            "subAppName": "ABC",
            "docs": [{
                "docTypes": [{
                    "docTypeName": "Deploy"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "subAppName": "DEF",
            "docs": [{
                "docTypes": [{
                    "docTypeName": "Deploy"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "subAppName": "GHI",
            "docs": [{
                "docTypes": {
                    "docTypeName": "Dev"
                },
                "docTypes": {
                    "docTypeName": "Deploy"
                },
                "docTypes": {
                    "docTypeName": "Support"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

var apps = data.apps;
var appsLen = apps.length;
for (var i = 0; i < appsLen; i++) {
    var app = apps[i];
  var appName = app.appName;
  console.log(appName);

  var subApps = app.subApps;
  var subAppsLen = subApps.length;
  for (var j = 0; j < subAppsLen; j++) {
    var subApp = subApps[j];
    var subAppName = subApp.subAppName;
    console.log("\t" + subAppName);

    var docs = subApp.docs;
    var docsLen = docs.length;
    for (var k = 0; k < docsLen; k++) {
        var doc = docs[k];
      var docTypes = doc.docTypes;
            var docTypesLen = docTypes.length;
      for (var l = 0; l < docTypesLen; l++) {
        var docType = docTypes[l];
        var docTypeName = docType.docTypeName;
        console.log("\t\t" + docTypeName);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I’m looping through the `data` variable, trying to print the following structure to the console, but I can’t for the life of me get the docTypeName(s) under GHI - *Dev, Deploy, Support* - to print:

```
App1
        ABC
                Deploy
        DEF
                Deploy
        GHI
                Dev
                Deploy
                Support
```

Does anyone see what I’m doing wrong? Part of me thinks it’s the object structure, but I’ve tried different variations and nothing works. I have to be overlooking something.

EDIT: Updated Fiddle with proper Object struct: https://jsfiddle.net/dzddv6pa/2/

Comment: If you want to use native Javascript why you tagged your question with jQuery?

Comment: Oops... That was a mistake. I seem to be making a lot of them tonight. :o I fixed the tags. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is not valid. There are duplicate keys in your object.

Comment: FYI, what you have is a *JavaScript object*. Object literals and JSON are two very different things. Your problem has nothing to do with JSON at all.

Comment: Yes, Felix, you are correct. In this example it is an Object Literal. But, outside of the Fiddle, it's actually being served as JSON, and parsed in the same manner, so I took the liberty of calling it JSON. My apologies for the confusion. Thanks to others who noted the mistake in the structure. All best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have duplicate properties in a javascript object. You should make `docTypes` be an array if you want to have multiple of them.

```
{
  "subAppName": "GHI",
  "docs": [{
    "docTypes": [{
      "docTypeName": "Dev"
    }, {
      "docTypeName": "Deploy"
    }, {
      "docTypeName": "Support"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Ah... Of course! I had a feeling it was in the structure. Thanks much!